# Update row with value from next row sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following columns in a SQLite DB.

```
id,ts,origin,product,bid,ask,nextts
1,2016-10-18 20:20:54.733,SourceA,Dow,1.09812,1.0982,
2,2016-10-18 20:20:55.093,SourceB,Oil,7010.5,7011.5,
3,2016-10-18 20:20:55.149,SourceA,Dow,18159.0,18161.0,
```

How can I populate the 'next timestamp' column (nextts) with the next timestamp for the same product (ts), from the same source? I've been trying the following, but I can't seem to put a subquery in an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE TEST a SET nextts = (select ts  
   from TEST b 
   where b.id> a.id and a.origin = b.origin and a.product = b.product
   order by id asc limit 1);
```

If I call this, I can display it, but I haven't found a way of updating the value yet.

```
select a.*, 
  (select ts  
   from TEST b 
   where b.id> a.id and a.origin = b.origin and a.product = b.product
   order by id asc limit 1) as nextts
from TEST a
order by origin, a.id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error message secret.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using table alias for table in `UPDATE` statement, which is not allowed. You can skip alias from there and use unaliased (but table-name prefixed) reference to its columns (while keeping aliased references for the `SELECT`), like this:

```
UPDATE TEST
   SET nextts = (
           SELECT b.ts
             FROM TEST b
            WHERE b.id > TEST.id AND 
                  TEST.origin = b.origin AND 
                  TEST.product = b.product
            ORDER BY b.id ASC
            LIMIT 1
       );
```

Prefixing unaliased column references with the table name is necessary for SQLite to identify that you're referencing to unaliased table. Otherwise the `id` column whould be understood as the `id` from the closest[*] possible data source, in which case it's the aliased table (as `b` alias), while we're interested in the unaliased table, therefore we need to explicitly tell SQLite that.

[*] Closest data source is the one listed in the same query, or parent query, or parent's parent query, etc. SQLite is looking for the first data source (going from inner part to the outside) in the query hierarchy that defines this column.

Comment: For some reason that's returning null. If I do this, it works: `where b.id = 5`. I also tried this, but to no avail. `where cast(b.id as Integer) > cast(id as Integer)`.

Comment: I've updated answer. I've tested it against your sample csv data and it works for me now.